# Mew gives SMTP error when trying to send through GMail

Tags: email, emacs, gmail

I'm trying to send an email using the GMail SMTP server.

I have the following setup for mew in emacs:

```
(default
     (mailbox-type 'imap)
     (proto "%")
     (imap-user my-email)
     (imap-server "imap.gmail.com")
     (imap-ssl t)
     (smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
     (smtp-auth-list ("PLAIN" "LOGIN" "CRAM-MD5"))
     (smtp-user my-email)
     (user my-username)
     (mail-domain "gmail.com")
     (name my-name)
     (imap-friend-folder "%from")
     (imap-trash-folder "%[Gmail]/All Mail"))
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The error message is this: `530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. dr7sm13115113qab.26.  This mail has been queued to +queue`

What mew configuration settings do I have to change to make this problem go away?

Comment: You didn't say what you are doing when you get this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I forgot to set the variable `smtp-ssl` to `t` so that the SMTP connection uses SSL (which GMail requires).